# Mouse cursor clicks on "wrong" screen

Tags: 16.04, unity, multiple-monitors, mouse, lightdm

I use ubuntu (16.04) in a dual-monitor setup.

When first set the screens position on unity control center, it didn't apply to all users and also didn't work on login screen. So I heard that it should work (on login screen) just by copying my `~/.config/monitors.xml` to `/var/lib/lightdm/.config`. So i just did it with a cp command and changed the ownership of the file correctly.

What happened was a strange behavior of my mouse cursor, it appear on one of the screens but behaves as it is on the other. It clicks on the wrong screen, not where it is. I hope this explanation is clear enough. Also, I should add that this only happens in login screen. After I login everything works fine.

I didn't find any bug report about this kind of behavior. Anyone has a tip on how to fix or debug the issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

Rearrange the desktops the way you want and put the computer on suspend mode. After you log into it, the problem got fixed.

Comment: My mouse was suddenly clicking below where it showed on my external screen. I first tried changing its mode (to mirrored or single display) and back which did not help. Then, although sceptical, I suspended my laptop due to this answer and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:
https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=349126

I had the same issue. Try unplugging any USB devices and plugging back in.  Try them in different USB ports.

If that doesn't work take a look at these different solutions:

- [Mouse on wrong display](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974079/mouse-on-wrong-display)
- [Can't right click on or place icons on second monitor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1145596/cant-right-click-on-or-place-icons-on-second-monitor)