# Mouse on wrong display

Tags: mouse, display

I installed Ubuntu today and my 2 monitors were not arranged in the right way (had to move mouse on the left screen to the left to get to the right screen). However I thought to fix the problem by going into the display settings and arrange them the way I want them to. This kind of fixed the problem. But now my mouse is displayed on the wrong screen. When I see the cursor on the left screen it is actually on the right screen and the other way arround. So I see the the cursor on one screen, but the mouse registers the clicks on the other screen. I had to change the dsiplay settings back to default to solve the issue.
Is there another way to fix the problem?

Comment: Physically swap the monitors

Comment: Well if there is no fix in Ubuntu I guess I have to do this. But I hoped there is a fix.

Comment: Well, normally your software fix works , but I have seen several graphics cards that do not like software fixes (not sure why). Normally the heads are marked "1" , "2", and "3" etc on the adapter. If you connect the hardware "wrong" results can be unexpected.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced this problem in Kubuntu 22.04 too. The way I managed to fix it was to first move my left monitor on top (stacked vertically) and applied changes, then I moved the top monitor to the left and applied changes.

Note, however, that this needs to be repeated if you need to log in again e.g. if you shut down your machine.

Answer (score 1):

Over 2 years later, but I just had this issue and figured maybe I could help someone in the future.

After trying a ton of different stuff, I didn't want to switch my physical monitors around, so I tried switching the spots into which my monitors were plugged into my GPU (both monitors are HDMI). This completely solved the problem for me.

Comment: ubuntu 20.10 fixed this issue

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to delete `$HOME/.config/monitors.xml`. I noticed this file contained id's which could explain the odd behaviour.

What happened in my case was my login prompt was shown in the wrong monitor (it's a sim rig dual screen). I switched DP cables, which solved this problem but created the displaced mouse.

Answer (score 1):

I only deleted the `~/.config/monitors.xml` and let my PC do a reboot. It solved the problem. It only happened to me after I swapped my Graphics Card, something was messing up the config file. Now everything works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem in 20.04 in a VM on Win10. Looking back it was caused by one of the monitors getting unplugged and Win10 switching them in the background. When I shutdown the VM I noticed the problem had nothing to do with Ubuntu. Fixed after I fixed and changed the displays in Win10. Starting the VM again and voila... problem was gone.