# Can't right click on or place icons on second monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, icons

I'm using ubuntu budgie and was wondering if it was possible to make it so I'm able to put icons on or be able to right click on my second monitor. Not sure if it's a bug or if it just isn't something you can't do by default but when I right click I just get a **very** small gray rectangle like this:

[image]

and if I drag an icon over it just snaps back.

Comment: can you rightclick on the primairy screen?

Comment: Yep! Everything else works totally normally. I can right click within windows on the second monitor too, just not the desktop itself, which isn't a big deal but I would like to be able to put icons on it if possible.

Comment: So apparently if I switch my display mode away from "join displays" and then back the problem goes away, but it comes back when I restart.

Comment: Seems a tiny bug. Could you try to run `rm ~/.config/monitors.xml`, immediately log out and back in? If that doesn't help, we could probably work around, but let' s see.

Comment: That reset my display settings but the problem stayed.

Comment: What worked for me was right click on primary display and in one of the menu that comes up, select "show icons on both displays". Works even after reboot

Comment: @thymethyme did you find the solution? I have the same problem in `20.04` for a secondary monitor of 42 inches with 1920 x 1080 resolution and using `Join Displays` - I use the "extend" approach, to move some Windows (Firefox, IDE) from the primary to the secondary monitor to do something ...

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem on Ubuntu 20.04.3. This problem appeared when I enabled the "Dock auto-hide" option in the settings. Disabling the Ubuntu Dock auto-hide feature fixed it. Also, try setting up the Dock on the main monitor.